# How do you sort an array of structs in Swift 5.x (macOS app)

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, cocoa, swift5

I have an struct array that is being added to a NSTableView. I've done a lot of searching and I can't find a way to sort it by clicking on the column header. This is question #1, is there a way to do this?

Question #2... how do I sort a struct array. Here is my struct

```
struct Person {
    let firstname: String
    let lastname: String
    let title: String
    let address: String
    let city: String
    let state: String
    let country: String
}

var people: [Person] = []
```

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated. I just don't know where to start. If my data was not in a struct array it's much easier. :(  But, I need this struct array :(

THANK YOU!

Comment: sorry, I changed the name for the purpose of this thread. for privacy issues.  and sadly no it does not help much :(

Comment: `people.sort { $0.whatEver < $1.whatEver }`

Comment: may I ask.  what does .whatEver mean? (dumb question for sure... ) and thank you!   would it be like,  $0.firstname ??

Comment: yes you just need to choose any property as long as its type conform to Comparable and it is not declared as optional

Comment: one more dumb question for you.  what is < doing for me?  what if I just want to sort the entire struct by first name or last name?  I just tried this and it seems to work but it gives me weird results.  like sorted but not totally...  Thank you Leo! You are awesome!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by not totally sorted. If you need first name and last name just use `sorted { ($0.firstname + $0.lastname) < ($1.firstname + $1.lastname) }`

Comment: I'm an idiot... .whatever is the same.. so $0.fistname < $1.firstname.  it worked. now I need to figure out how to make this work by clicking a column header! :) THANK YOU @LeoDabus

Comment: Leo, `sorted { ($0.lastname, $0.firstname) < ($1.lastname, $1.firstname) }` would work better. It would sort by last name, and then by first name within people with the same last name. Your solution would sort people by a string built from combining the first and last names, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @DuncanC considering that OP is using a NSTableView and sorting by column this wouldn't matter as he would need to be using sort descriptors instead of manually sorting the collection. Note that this sort wouldn't make any sense here in Brazil. It all depends on your location costume.

Comment: @DouglasBrown https://www.dropbox.com/s/gur1a7otwv1lspi/Table%20View%20Sample.zip?dl=1

Comment: OH my @LeoDabus I did not see this.. WOW!  I will look at it. THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: @LeoDabus ok, I copied everything from your code into mine and all works but the column sorting. no clue why.... could I send you my code and have you take a FAST look?

Comment: @LeoDabus my guess is your are using the '@objcMembers class Person: NSObject' and I'm just doing this in the struc array .... mmmmmmm. I don't see anything else wrong or different from what you did in your example

Comment: @LeoDabus don't laugh too hard... I'm learning but feel free to laugh ;)  if you see anything. I would be forever in your debt. would love to do something for you too, if possible. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ugqb078anq3cvno/OysterCollector.zip?dl=0

Comment: I will take a look

Comment: @DouglasBrown you need to use a class and it needs to inherit NSObject

Comment: This I what I figured. I think I remember reading this too..  the problem was with the json .... but you will see.. it's not a big app. I'm just getting started and I'm having fun with it. lots..  it's just a hobby for me but in due time I might have something fun for me ;0  THANK YOU @LeoDabus

Comment: @DouglasBrown first you need to apply a string transform to your server response. It has some invalid character sequence for Swift. You need to transform Hex/Java to Any/character https://www.dropbox.com/s/91wt3ud7h2hgbq9/MyPlayground%20Swift%205.4%20MACOS.playground.zip?dl=1

Comment: it will transform `"title": "D\u00e9j\u00e0 Vu"` into `"title": "Déjà Vu"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232444/discussion-between-douglas-brown-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @DouglasBrown https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbky7cmjsufvcxg/OysterCollector.zip?dl=1